# Cron vs queued task

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks

My application has an *Order* model with an *execution_datetime* attribute. I'd like to send some distinct notifications. For example

- *execution_datetime* minus 12 hours: email to carrier
- *execution_datetime* minus 3 hours: sms to customer
- *execution_datetime* plus 1 hour: email to customer

The above timings are not strict and can be approximated; slight deviations are acceptable. Also, the *execution_datetime* can change in the meantime...

I'm unsure whether to use cron or queued tasks for this. Some thoughts of my own:

Cron:

- Business logic will need to be written to fetch applicable orders and execute accordingly
- Is execution guaranteed? Should some sort of database flag be implemented to indicate a notification has been sent, and then perhaps fetch all due orders that are unflagged as some sort of failsafe?

Queued tasks:

- Task is scheduled on creation of the order? If so, suppose the execution time is changed. How to modify the scheduled task? You'd need to somewhere keep track of the task ID?
- Or perhaps a cron job that mass schedules applicable tasks every day?

I look forward to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Great question! I am interested in this discussion.Let me chip in with a scenario from my personal experience.

In my application, I have a `Listing` model and they have a `promotion_ends_at` column. Obviously, the listing promotion ends sometimes in the future.

So, like you also mentioned, there are two ways to do this.

1. When the listing is created, I could queue a job that will end the promotion on the listing in the future). The delay of that job would be the time the promotion has to end (and that could me months away).
2. I could also have a cron job that runs regularly that manages listings that their promotions should end on a specific date.

We were using `SQS` as our queue service and since the maximum delay on `SQS` is 15 mins, option 1 was not feasible. We, then, moved to Redis where we could queue delayed jobs with a long delay easily.

However, like you also said, the `promotion_ends_at` column could be updated during that time. So, either, you would have to keep track of the job to de-queue it or you could re-check whether the job should still run when it is about to execute.

For example, you could `fresh()` the model and check whether your condition is still valid. In my case, I would `fresh` my `Listing` and check if the `promotion_ends_at` is in the past. However, this means that we would have a lot of stale jobs that would probably be **discarded** anyway.

We finally went with a simple cron job that mass schedules the job on the day that they need to be run. I also think that running delayed jobs is a business logic and maybe the queue shouldn't be held responsible for running jobs delayed far too much in the future.

Comment: Sounds like a comparable scenario indeed. Thanks for chiming in.